# Fresh Sitecore install - Handler "AboMapperCustom-88978986" has a bad module "IsapiModule" in its module list

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I get this error with a fresh Sitecore 6.4 install.

> HTTP Error 500.21 - Internal Server Error Handler
>   "AboMapperCustom-88978986" has a bad module "IsapiModule" in its
>   module list

Any ideas? AppPool is integreated but i get same error on classic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem with the installer it sets up the appPool using .net 2.0. If you switch it to use .net 4.0 and make sure it's in integrated mode, you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I was using Windows 7 and Sitecore 7.5. This solved the HTTP Error 500.21 for me:

Run the command prompt as administrator.
Go to this directory: %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\
And run the command: aspnet_regiis -i

Hope this can help.